# How can I add metadata to PNG images on OS X/Linux?

Tags: metadata, png

Is there a program for OS X and Linux that I can use to add [Textual information](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11textinfo) to PNG image files? Something for Windows also, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The "comment" field of PNG files can be edited with [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), however I'm not sure about the other fields. To do this in GIMP, open the image and select "Image" from the toolbar, then "Image Properties". From the "Image Properties" dialog, select the "Comment" tab.

GIMP is also available for both Linux, Windows and Mac OS X.